# bundler not install new gems in proup

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, bundler

I am upgrading a rails3.0 app to Rails3.1
I am following railscast 282

I decided not to use sass

```
group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

I run bundle install

now I wont to add sass-rails gem to assets so I changed gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

gem do not installs

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'sass-rails (= 3.1.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but just removing the gem version worked

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```